# How to find server name when installing SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to install SQL Server 2008 R2, so I need to put "server name", I tried my computer name but I got an exception, would you tell me how to find it please

[image]

```
and this is the exception ![enter image description here][2]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `.` in the server name to get yours. Or from the server manager you can get the full computer name

Comment: As Mahmoud stated, use `.` or localhost. Yet another options is 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal do u mean that i just put "." or ".ComputerName" ?

Comment: Here's a few more options if you feel adventurous: http://mssqlforum.com/threads/connecting-to-a-local-sql-instance.39/#post-63

Comment: @user569711 do u mean to put 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: If you install many versions of sql, use `.\SQL2008`

Comment: i tried put 127.0.0.1 put i got that excpetion

Comment: @totti roma - what exception?

Comment: @tottiroma Just `.` with out the computer name.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal i tried but still that exception

Comment: @user569711 i will edit the question with the exception , check please

Comment: The screenshot you showed in image 1 looks like SQL Server Management Studio, which is a client management tool, used to connect to a pre-installed server. Did you install the database engine as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `.\SQLEXPRESS` as the server name.

Check this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLrxFXXeLFk)

**EDIT:-**

From the comments below posted by the user(thought that it is useful)

> You can install SQL Server as an instance, which allows you to run
>   multiple environments on the same machine (ie. localhost\dev and
>   localhost\prod). If you install MSSQL Server Express, it defaults the
>   instance name to localhost\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: i print the exception , would you check the question now please

Comment: Did you installed the database engine as well?

Comment: i can't check the video , i am connection to internet using deal up , sorry , would you tell me what should i do ?

Comment: Could you plz try .\SQLEXPRESS and tell whats returning?

Comment: you the one mane , ".\SQlEXPRESS" works , thaaaaaaaank you very very much

Comment: @totti roma - Just to explain what eactually happened. You can install SQL Server as an instance, which allows you to run multiple environments on the same machine (ie. `localhost\dev` and `localhost\prod`). 

If you install MSSQL Server Express, it defaults the instance name to `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`

Answer (score 1):

- Use `.` as the server name. Or
- From the server manager: Administration tools > Server Manager. You can get the computer name.

Comment: i know my computer name, i tired ".ComputerName" and it doesn't word :(

Comment: @tottiroma If you want to use he computer name write it without a `.`. Just `Computername`.

Comment: i do it and stil the exception :(

Comment: i print the exception , would you check the question now please

Answer (score 1):

Use .\SQLEXPRESS

or

Use REVAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS

REVAN-PC is my System Name

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Start
2. write in search box: ODBC
3. Go to system DSN tab
4. click on Add...
5. select SQL server option and finish
6. Go to 3th box (server:) and see your server!

Answer (score 0):

Try using (local) as server name. I had the same problem and after few attempts of connecting,(local) just came by default in the server name field.